# Standarized Betas values from regstats function

Tags: matlab

I am conducting a multiple linear regression analysis with the `result = regstats(y,X,model)` function. I would like to know where are the **Standarized Betas** values stored in the `result` structure? If they are not given by this function, how can I obtain them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found how to do it:

```
standardized_beta_values = zscore(result.tstat.beta)
```

Am I right?